# Spring boot 2.1.0 error when trying to bootstrap Hibernate asynchronously

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm upgrading my application to Spring 2.1.0 and one of the new things I was trying to use is Hibernate asynchronously bootstrap.

But when I'm adding a flag `spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=deferred` to configuration then application throws error during startup:

> Parameter 0 of method entityManagerFactory in
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration
>   required a single bean, but 2 were found:
>   - [ ]     - applicationTaskExecutor: defined by method 'applicationTaskExecutor' in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.class]
>     - taskScheduler: defined by method 'taskScheduler' in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration.class]

Looks like Spring have trouble with finding unique `AsyncTaskExecutor` bean but both beans are coming from auto configuration.
To make it work I excluded `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration` because right now I'm not using it but I don't really like this approach:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableScheduling
class MyApp {}
```

Any ideas how to fix it properly? Seems to me like a bug in spring boot.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, you might want to create a GitHub issue for this.

Comment: bug has been [reported](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15038)

Comment: Bug has been fixed in spring boot 2.1.2